# Send accelerator with mouse to perform selection of text

Tags: java, swing, textselection, accelerator

I need to make selection of text using mouse instead of ctrl+A
I tried:

```
sendAcceleratorKey(MouseEvent.BUTTON1, "");
```

but I don't know which argument could I set to say make a click with mouse and let the mouse enforced to select the text.

Comment: I have no idea what the `sendAcceleratorKey` method is since it is not part of the (JDK6) API. There is no method that I know of that will drag the mouse from the beginning of the text component to the end of the text component. What is the point of this?

Answer (score 1):

If the text is in a [`JTextComponent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html), [`selectAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#selectAll%28%29) may be a suitable choice in your `MouseListener`.

Addendum: You may also be able to leverage the `select-all` [`Action`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html), which is [bound](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>meta</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> by default on various platforms.

Your [sscce](http://sscce.org/) may be helpful in deciding. There's a related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525154/jtextfields-settext-method-doesnt-work-from-a-keylistener/7525904#7525904).

Comment: it is a textArea , and I want to make the selection on first displayed text using mouse, how could I use selectAll ?

Comment: There are related examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178312/how-to-select-all-text-in-a-jformattedtextfield-when-it-gets-focus).